# Object pooling with .wait and .notify

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, wait, notify

I'm trying to create a class in java that pool objects. The class starts creating the minimum amount of objects required, when the requests start to kick in, every thread checks if there a object available, if it can create it because the maximum has not been reached yet, or if otherwise it has to wait to get one.

The idea is the threads needs to synchronize to get/create an engine, but they can process in parallel (`ProcessWithEngine` method). The processing could take a couple of minutes, and apparently it's working as I want.

The problem is, that **sometimes** when `.notify()` has been called and a thread is released from the `.wait()`, the queue has 0 items, and that should be impossible because just before `.notify()`, an item is added.

What could be the problem?

The code is like this:

```
Queue _queue = new Queue();

int _poolMax = 4;
int _poolMin = 1;
int _poolCurrent =0;


public void Process(Object[] parameters) throws Exception
{
    Engine engine = null;

    synchronized(_queue) 
    {
        if(_queue.isEmpty() && _poolCurrent >= _poolMax)
        { 
            _queue.wait();

            // HERE : sometimes _queue.isEmpty() is true at this point.

            engine = (SpreadsheetEngine)_queue.dequeue();

        }
        else if (_queue.isEmpty() && _poolCurrent < _poolMax)
        {               
            engine = CreateEngine();
            _poolCurrent++;
        }
        else
        {               
            engine = (Engine)_queue.dequeue();
        }   
    }

    ProcessWithEngine(engine, parameters);


    // work done
    synchronized(_queue) 
    {
        _queue.enqueue(engine);

        _queue.notify();
    }
}
```

I've *fixed* it doing this:

```
            do
            {
                _queue.wait();

            }
            while(_queue.isEmpty());
```

But basically this means that a thread is losing its turn, and it could mean a timeout later on.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not enquing null engine? try to insert this check on "work done" if (engine!=null) then {_queue.enqueue(engine); _queue.notify();}

Comment: Yes sure, actually that line that is commented was an actual line before, and I could check that the queue was empty.

Comment: Probably readers and writers pattern could solve your problem: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/book_applets/ReadersWriters.html

Comment: @vtortola - Can you please provide complete code for this, need for understanding purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All calls to `.wait()` have to be enclosed in a `while` loop.  Calls to `wait()` can just randomly wake up.

Per the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29): "As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop:"

Comment: "spurious wakeups" ? Fantastic. I'm gonna put it in a thread and launch a test with lots of threads and see what happen. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

With you solution, doesn't every thread enter an endless wait()?

The normal idiom is something like this:

```
synchronized(stuff) {
  while (mustWait) 
     wait();
  // do things with stuff
}
```

On the other hand, since you're already using a Queue, why not make it a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue` and get a concurrency solution for free?

Comment: I just did the loop. I cannot use BlockinQueue because it doesn't exist in my environment. The environments is a old Java IDE from SAP, it doesn't have generic or anything new, I think is Java 1.

Comment: Oh my! May the force be with you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible for at least two reasons:

- Spurious wakeups, as noted by Justin Waugh
- Another thread acquires a lock and calls `dequeue()` in between - after the first thread called `notify()` and finished its `synchornized` block, but before the second thread actually woke up from its `wait()`. It's possible because `synchronized`/`wait()`/`notify()` doesn't guarantee *fairness*.

Therefore `wait()` should be always used inside a loop:

```
while (_queue.isEmpty())
    _queue.wait();
```

Comment: All the thread logic is enclosed in that method, and the queue is used only there. So it's probably the fist option. I'm doing a test right now. thanks.

Comment: @vtortola: But method is called by many threads, right? So, new call may occur in between.